# Transposing a matrix

Tags: c, matrix, transpose

I want to transpose a matrix, its a very easy task but its not working with me :

**UPDATE**

I am transposing the first matrix and
storing it in a second one
The two
arrays point to the same structure
I
need two arrays (target and source)
so I can display them later for
comparison.

```
struct testing{
  int colmat1;
  int rowmat1;
  float mat[64][64];
};

int testtranspose(testing *test,testing *test2){
  int i,j;
  test2->colmat1 = test->rowmat1;
  test2->rowmat1 = test->colmat1
  for(i=0;i<test->rowmat1;i++){
    for(j=0;j<test->colmat1;j++){
      test2->mat[i][j] = test->mat[i][j];
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

I thought this is the correct method of doing it, but apparently for a matrix such as :

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
```

I get :

```
1 2 0 0
3 4 0 0
```

What is the problem ?

Please help,
Thanks !

Comment: What's the contents of the `testing` type?

Comment: I don't know how to transpose a matrix correctly, but all you've done is copy over the values. Look at what actually happens in your loop - it's just an assignment.

Comment: FYI, I replaced `(*x).` with `x->` in your code.

Comment: What's the difference between the pairs of fields `rowsmat1,colsmat1` and `rowsmat2,colsmat2`?

Comment: @David : I updated the question --- @MG Im looking through it now --- @Interjay they point to the same structure but rowmat2 is the new row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To transpose the matrix, you need to change rows and columns. So you need to use:

```
targetMatrix[i][j] = sourceMatrix[j][i];
```

Note how the order of i,j is changed, since one matrix's rows are another's columns.

By the way, instead of `(*a).b`, you can write `a->b`. This is the normal way of accessing a field of a struct pointer.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I just did :  `((*test2).mat[i][j])=((*test).mat[j][i]); `  but this gave me an error in the code ..

Comment: @Zazu: don't surround the left side of the assignment with parantheses. Just use `test2->mat[i][j] = test->mat[j][i];`

Comment: Do I remove the first 2 lines of the code ? `test2->colmat2 = test->rowmat1; test2->rowmat2 = test->colmat1` -- I thought this is how I move contents of each row and col oppositely.

Comment: The code you posted won't compile since the `testing` struct doesn't have these fields. You still need these 2 lines, but you need to access the fields `colmat` and `rowmat`.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake copying the code here, colmat1 and rowmat1 ARE the ones in the structure -- Code updated

Comment: In that case you need these two lines: They are in charge of assigning the target matrix's size correctly. However, they won't rearrange the elements themselves - for that you need to do what I showed in my answer.

Comment: @interjay, you're right, The code worked !! I had to keep the `test2->colmat2 = test->rowmat1; test2->rowmat2 = test->colmat1` syntax, and reverse `[i][j]` for the source matrix ... it works !! Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
   struct testing{
  int colmat;
  int rowmat;
  float mat[64][64];
};

int testtranspose(testing *test,testing *test2){
  int i,j;
  test2->colmat = test->rowmat;
  test2->rowmat = test->colmat;
  for(i=0;i<test->rowmat;i++){
    for(j=0;j<test->colmat;j++){
      test2->mat[j][i] = test->mat[i][j];
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
int printmat(testing* mat)
{
    for(int i=0;i<mat->rowmat;i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(int j=0;j<mat->colmat;j++)
            printf(("  %f"),mat->mat[i][j]);
    }
    return 0;
}

            // 2
// main.cpp
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    testing mat1, mat2;
    memset(&mat1,0,sizeof(testing));
    memset(&mat2,0,sizeof(testing));
    mat1.colmat =2;
    mat1.rowmat =3;
    for(int i=0;i<mat1.rowmat;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<mat1.colmat;j++)
            mat1.mat[i][j] = (float)rand();
    }
    printmat(&mat1);
    testtranspose(&mat1,&mat2);
    printmat(&mat2);
    getchar();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply !! I see how this code works, and I understood it :) I implemented some parts but some others have commands I didnt hear of before (memset,printmat)..Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I am new to C / C++ (3rd day or so :) ) and I had the same problem. My approach was slightly different in that I thought it would be nice to have a function that would return a transposed matrix. Unfortunately, as I found out, you cannot return a an array nor pass an array to a function in C++ (let alone a double array), but you can pass / return a pointer which works similar to an array. So this is what I did:

```
int * matrix_transpose(int * A, int A_rows, int A_cols){
    int * B;
    int B_rows, B_cols;
    B_rows = A_cols; B_cols= A_rows;
    B = new int [B_rows*B_cols];
    for(int i=0;i<B_rows;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<B_cols;j++){
            B[i*B_cols+j]=A[j*A_cols+i];
        }
    }
    return B;
};
```

The trick was in dynamic arrays. I used A_rows and B_rows as separate names (you can use only rows and cols) in order to make the problem less intricate and less confusing when reading code.

```
B = new int [rows*cols] // This is cool in C++.
```